# Excel ODBC connection to MS SQL server refresh issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, connection, pivot-table, sql-server, odbc

I've created an ODBC connection in Excel in order to create pivots on a large table held in MS SQL Server.

The connection string looks like this:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=ExperienceStudy;Data Source=CRDBACTD01\SQLDEV01;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=USCRDKKNFX2;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False
```

I went ahead and disabled any automatic/background refreshing within the connection properties. However, periodically (like every 15 minutes), the workbook halts and appears to be refreshing for about 2 minutes. There's nothing in the status bar indicating that it's actually refreshing but I don't know what else it would be doing. After that 2 minutes of being stalled, I can use the workbook normally again, add new pivot tables, edit them, etc with no interruption or lag.

Does anyone have an idea of what is actually happening during this time and if I can prevent it?

Here are my Excel details:
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2203 Build 16.0.15028.20240) 32-bit.

Comment: Are automatic backup/saves enabled?  Is anti-virus on-access scanning enabled?  Is it a large Excel workbook?  Are you saving it to a network share or the cloud?  Are group policy settings being applied?  Try setting a breakpoint in your VBA code near the ODBC call, then wait 15 minutes.  If the breakpoint doesn't trip, then it's likely something else.